# Algorithm avice: How to find the most recent date (javascript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date

I am trying to add a function to my website that sorts through dates in formats like this "Apr 5, 2016, 5:56 PM" and figuring out if it is more recent than this "Apr 5, 2016, 9:56 AM" and by how long in (hours say). I know it would have to do with figuring out the month, then the year, then the hour and comparing them. Does anyone have any advice/samples on how to do this in javascript? it is really bugging me?

Thanks

Comment: Convert the string to timestamp using `+new Date(dateString)` and sort by timestamps.

Comment: Will it convert directly without feeding it through something?

Comment: *"feeding it through something"*, like a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always manually parse date strings, do not use *Date.parse* or the Date constructor (which are equivalent for parsing). A library can help, but if you only have a single format, a bespoke function can do the job, e.g.

```js
// Apr 5, 2016, 5:56 PM
function parseDateString(s) {
  var months = {jan:0,feb:1,mar:2,apr:3,may:4,jun:5,
                jul:6,aug:7,sep:8,oct:9,nov:10,dec:11};
  var b = s.match(/\w+/g);
  var h = b[3]%12 + (/am/i.test(s)? 0 : 12);
  return new Date(b[2], months[b[0].toLowerCase()], b[1], h, b[4]);
}

var s = 'Apr 5, 2016, 5:56 PM';
document.write(parseDateString(s));
```

If you need a more general parser, there is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) but it may be way more than you need. If you just need a small parser and formatter, consider a utility like [date-format.js](https://github.com/barbir/js-date-format/blob/master/js/date-format.js) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you out:

```
var date1 = new Date("7/13/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/15/2010");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Comment: The date I get comes from a ios/android app and must be in that format.

Comment: So ideally I would change that format to something easier but it is stuck for now unless it goes through another week long app store approval.

Comment: Please don't suggest parsing strings with the Date constructor, it's largely implementation dependent and inconsistent. Far better to manually parse the string using a library or simple function if only one or two formats need to be supported.